# AngularJs not able to send post param to PHP service

Tags: php, angularjs

I have hosted a service on my php server and want to consume that using my angularjs app but somehow i am not able to send post params from angularjs
Below are my code

```
angular.module('pixyfi', ['ngMaterial']).controller('productGridController',function($scope, $http){
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/getFeed.php',
                params:{
                    user:16,
                    friends:5,
                    page:1,
                    token:1
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
            })
        })
```

in php Receiving params as

```
$friends=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['friends']);
$page=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['page']);
$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user']);
$token = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['token']);
```

Please let me know what i am missing

For testing purpose i created test.Post.php which takes ID as post param and echo it.
PHP Code

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo "ID ".$id;
?>
```

Angular JS Code

```
 $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : '/testPost.php',
          data    : {"id":"1"}, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              // Showing errors.
              $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
              $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.username;
              $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
            } else {
              $scope.message = data.message;
            }
          });
```

But again its not working. Please suggest what changes should i make?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the 'params' option is for GET parameters, not POST.  See the docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Also note there is the convenient $http.post method for when you wish to make a POST request.

So you could try:

```
angular.module('pixyfi', ['ngMaterial']).controller('productGridController',function($scope, $http){
            $http.post('/getFeed.php', {
                user:16,
                friends:5,
                page:1,
                token:1
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
            })
        })
```

Comment: its not working as well. Just for testing i created testPost.php which takes ID as post Param and echo that. Please see updated code